# Parsing a site with dynamic content

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, parsing, nokogiri

I'm using Nokogiri to parse TechCrunch [with a specific search term.

http://techcrunch.com/search/education#stq=education&stp=1

The problem is that the site has a delay of a few seconds before it returns a list related to the search item, so the URL I input to Nokogiri to parse is empty of relevant content when Nokogiri retrieves it.

The content appears to load after a couple of seconds dynamically - I'm guessing Javascript.
Any ideas of how to retrieve the HTML with a slight delay?

Comment: You need to make the request for the dynamically loaded content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Ruby method, `sleep`

```rb
seconds_to_delay = 5
sleep seconds_to_delay
```

---

Edit 1: Dealing with divs that load some time after the document finishes loading

I hate this scenario. I had to deal with exact same scenario, so here's how I solved it.
You need to use something like [selenium-webdriver](http://rubygems.org/gems/selenium-webdriver) gem.

```rb
require 'selenium-webdriver'
url = "http://techcrunch.com/search/education#stq=education&stp=1"

css_selector = ".tab-panel.active"

driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
driver.get(url)
driver.switch_to.default_content
posts_text = driver.find_element(:css, css_selector).text
puts posts_text
driver.quit
```

If you are running this on some virtual machine on Heroku, AWS EC2 or Digital Ocean and stuff, you can't use firefox. Instead you need a headless browser like phantom.js.

In order to use phantom.js instead of firefox, first, install phantomjs on the VM. Then change to `driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :phantomjs`.

You can use [this gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/phantomjs) that actually installs phantomjs for you.

---

Second edit for question b)

```rb
require 'selenium-webdriver'
url = "http://techcrunch.com/search/education#stq=education&stp=1"

css_selector = ".tab-panel.active ul.river-compact.river-search li"

driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :phantomjs
driver.get(url)
driver.switch_to.default_content
items = driver.find_elements(:css, css_selector)
items.each {|x| puts x }
driver.quit
```

Comment: The problem is that the get request via Nokogiri gets an empty page, the contents of which is loaded by Javascript and appears after a few seconds. So I don't think this will help. Thanks for the method heads-up though, v interesting one

Comment: I have faced this exact same problem before. I will edit my answer. `sleep 10_min` for me :)

Comment: Very curious. It actually launches Firefox for you! Is there any way to a) not do that and b) loop through the <li> items as I would do in Nokogiri(doc.css('li').each {|link| puts link.content}) etc?

Comment: a) Right, if you don't want to use Firefox, you need to run headless browser like phantomjs. Phantomjs will mimic the real browser without actually opening a browser like Firefox or Chrome. See my instruction for using Phantomjs in the response.

Comment: Excellent, thanks. Last q - can you recommend a place to go to see how to traverse the Selenium nodes easily in this way? I want to grab partly text, and partly internal things like src attribute of an image.

Comment: Rake task in Terminal throws 'Unable to find phantomjs executable'... but that's for another thread :)

Comment: [Here is the link to selenium-webdriver doc for Ruby](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/rb/index.html)

Comment: `'Unable to find phantomjs executable'` sounds like phantomjs didn't install properly maybe.